# Is it possible to use AWS Cognito to configure a SAML/OIDC relationship for SP or IDP initiated SSO with Cognito acting as the IDP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

Using Auth0 as an example of what I want to achieve, it is possible to create an Auth0 application and configure a SAML trust relationship to a service provider by downloading Auth0's Identity Provider Metadata from a Auth0 SAML2 Web App and supplying that to the service provider, and also uploading the Service Provider metadata to Auth0. Supplying some other configuration options such as application callback URL to Auth0 then allows federation to be achieved into the test service provider via SP initiated SSO.

I would like to understand if it is possible to build such a relationship with AWS Cognito using either SAML or OIDC, where Cognito would be acting as the Identity Provider. There seems to be a lot of documentation available providing instructions on how to use SAML to create a relationship to a third-party identity provider for a user pool, but I'm struggling to find any documentation or options within the console to configure SSO to a test service provider, for example no reference to Cognito Identity Provider metadata. The assumption that I am making is that Cognito is a service only for authorisation with your own applications (such as user login) and does not support SSO into other services in the way that I describe, and that if you wanted to use Cognito as a Identity Provider then I would have to connect my user pools to a service such as Auth0 to then build out the SSO relationship. Am I correct in this assumption? and if not, please help me to understand where in the documentation/console I should be looking.

I'm also aware that AWS SSO exists and that I could potentially link a Cognito user pool to that, however the user pool will be made up of clients, and my assumption is that AWS SSO serves to specifically support (internal/affiliate) employee access to AWS services and resources, and should not be used as a way to enable SSO to another service for customers.